# Mysql where clause breaks calculated query

Tags: mysql

wonder if someone can point out the error in my code below. I have mysql query that displays sales leads by month, then calculates % of those converted to sales. If I add where clause to this it breaks the total column as it outputs the same as the Comms column?

```
  Select
  q.*,
  ROUND(100 * Comms / Total, 2) As Conversion,
  If(q.Adviser Is Null, 1, 0) As remove
From
  (Select
      a.ContactFullName As Adviser,
      SUM(YEAR(b.CaseDate) = 2013 AND Month(b.CaseDate) = 1) AS Jan,
      SUM(YEAR(b.CaseDate) = 2013 AND Month(b.CaseDate) = 2) As Feb,
      SUM(YEAR(b.CaseDate) = 2013 AND Month(b.CaseDate) = 3) As Mar,
      SUM(YEAR(b.CaseDate) = 2013 AND Month(b.CaseDate) = 4) As Apr,
      SUM(YEAR(b.CaseDate) = 2013 AND Month(b.CaseDate) = 5) As May,
      SUM(YEAR(b.CaseDate) = 2013 AND Month(b.CaseDate) = 6) As Jun,
      SUM(YEAR(b.CaseDate) = 2013 AND Month(b.CaseDate) = 7) As Jul,
      SUM(YEAR(b.CaseDate) = 2013 AND Month(b.CaseDate) = 8) As Aug,
      SUM(YEAR(b.CaseDate) = 2013 AND Month(b.CaseDate) = 9) As Sep,
      SUM(YEAR(b.CaseDate) = 2013 AND Month(b.CaseDate) = 10) As Oct,
      SUM(YEAR(b.CaseDate) = 2013 AND Month(b.CaseDate) = 11) As Nov,
      SUM(YEAR(b.CaseDate) = 2013 AND Month(b.CaseDate) = 12) As Dece,
      Count(b.CaseID) As Total,
      Sum(Case When Year(b.StatusSubmittedDate) = 2013 Then 1 Else 0
      End) As Comms

    From
      tblcontacts a Inner Join
```

Without WHERE clause it outputs;

```
Total - Comms - Conversion
479   -  148  - 30.9%
```

With WHERE clause it outputs;

```
Total - Comms - Conversion
148   -  148  - 100%
```

I cant work out why this has happened?

Kind Regards

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your input, I did try that but throws an error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax;'

Comment: @gary Updated my answer, should be correct and working now.

Comment: @tombom - Thanks again, using your code example if I change the years the comms column is spot on which is great, the total column however and all the months values stay the same regardless of year. If I enter 2012 or 2013 the total is the same 479? Thanks again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I rewrote your whole query:

```
Select
  q.*,
  totals.total,
  ROUND(100 * Comms / totals.total, 2) As Conversion
  If(q.Adviser Is Null, 1, 0) As remove
From
  (Select
      a.ContactFullName As Adviser,
      Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 1) As Jan,
      Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 2) As Feb,
      Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 3) As Mar,
      Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 4) As Apr,
      Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 5) As May,
      Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 6) As Jun,
      Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 7) As Jul,
      Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 8) As Aug,
      Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 9) As Sep,
      Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 10) As Oct,
      Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 11) As Nov,
      Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 12) As Dece,
      Count(b.StatusSubmittedDate) As Comms

    From
      tblcontacts a Inner Join
      tblcases b On a.ContactID = b.ContactAssignedTo 
      WHERE Year(b.StatusSubmittedDate) = 2013
    Group By
      a.ContactFullName With Rollup) q
    inner join (select  a.ContactFullName As Adviser, count(*) as total from
    tblcontacts a Inner Join
      tblcases b On a.ContactID = b.ContactAssignedTo 
      WHERE Year(b.StatusSubmittedDate) = 2013
      group by Adviser
      )totals on q.Adviser = totals.Adviser
```

**Original answer:**

To have multiple COUNTS you can workaround like this:

```
      Count(b.CaseID) As Total,
      SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(b.StatusSubmittedDate) = 2013 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Comms,
```

but this:

```
      ROUND(100 * Count(b.StatusSubmittedDate) / Count(b.CaseID),
```

won't work, since this calculation has to be done later.

```
Select
  q.*,
  ROUND(100 * Comms / Total, 2) As Conversion,
  If(q.Adviser Is Null, 1, 0) As remove
From
  (Select
      a.ContactFullName As Adviser,
      Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 1 and year(b.CaseDate) = 2012) As Jan,
      ... Dec,
      Count(b.CaseID) As Total,
      SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(b.StatusSubmittedDate) = 2013 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Comms
    From
      tblcontacts a Inner Join
      tblcases b On a.ContactID = b.ContactAssignedTo 
    Group By
      a.ContactFullName With Rollup) q
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you valued input. If I add the 'CASE WHEN' to my exiting query it displays the correct totals, however it dispays the same totals whatever year I enter. If I enter 2012 or 2112 the output is the same - If I use the second suggestion error is thrown '#1054 - Unknown column 'b.StatusSubmittedDate' in 'field list'. I tried moving the line about with no success. Thanks again..

Comment: For your first issue, you mean the totals per month? Of course you have to change those lines to `SUM(YEAR(b.CaseDate) = 2013 AND Month(b.CaseDate) = 1) AS Jan, ...`. For your second issue - did you try latest version of my answer? In outer query I wrote `ROUND(100 * Comms / Total, 2) As Conversion`

Comment: @gary Updated my answer, rewrote your whole query.

Comment: Really appreciate your time on this, I tried the latest version of your answer with the out query, just copied exact into query window. It works great but I am stuck on the totals column, it always displays 479 regardless of which year I query on. Thanks again..

Comment: Spotted a minor mistake, you have to put the where clause in both, the inner and outer query. Have a try again, please, with the rewritten query.

Comment: Hi there, tried te new code, the individual months values are fine as is the Comms field, its just the total field that always displays 479 regardless of year. If I change year to 2013 then January outputs 34 but total field outputs 479?

Comment: Well, isn't that what total is supposed to be? Total is everything, the 100%. Maybe you should make it more clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi there, sorry if I wasn't clear, the total is the total of that year, 479 is indeed the correct total for 2012 but for 2013 to date it should read 34 as per January's data. I am trying to have the total only count which year the rest of the query is based on.

Comment: It's because you use two different columns to count and filter by where clause. Use one for both, StatusSubmittedDate or CaseDate.

Comment: StatusSubmittedDate is the date the lead is classed as a sale, CaseDate is the lead date, so I calculate lead v sales to get a conversion rate. Oddly I have got it working by adding ' Sum(Case When Year(b.CaseDate) = 2013 Then 1 Else 0
      End) As Total,'. This seems to work whichever year I choose whereas count doesn't..